# Abstract function to access field in Java

Tags: java

Please allow me to apologize for the poor language in which I am describing the problem ... I simply don't know exactly how to phrase it best.  Does `MethodWhichPointsToOneOfTheMembersOfBla` exist and how can it be built?

```
public class Bla {

    public Integer bla1;
    public Integer bla2;

    // some methods

}

public class SomeClass {

    private Bla bla = new Bla();

    private MethodWhichPointsToOneOfTheMembersOfBla mwpt = new MethodWhichPointsToField(2); // or 1

    public setBla(Integer i) {
        mwpt(bla).set(i);
    }

    public Integer getBla() {
        return mwpt(bla).get();
    }

}
```

Please note that **do not** want to **use** a `switch` inside of `setBla`.

E.g., is there some form of abstract method which I could initialize to always point to the second field in `Bla`.

Comment: Did You read about official API? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: This can be done with [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html). Anyway that is a code smell and not a common way to do things in Java.

Comment: @dotwin What problem are you trying to solve with your `MWPT`? While it can be accomplished almost in the way you're looking for, it might not be the best way (in fact it's probably not the best way).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I will read more and look for alternatives then...